# Await Async when looping through large json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

The json file is large around 20mb.

I want to wait until a result is returned or the entire file is looped through, before sending back the age. Currently it returns 0 even if the age is not 0

```
const app = express()
const genesis = require('./people.json');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let age = getAge(req.query.name)
 
  res.json({
    “name”: req.query.name,
    “age”: age, // this is always 0
  });
});

function getAge(name) {
  genesis.balances.forEach(element => {
    if (element.name == name) {
      // console here shows correct age
      return element.person[0].age;
    }
  });
  return 0;
}


app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Your getAge() method is not doing what you think it might be doing :)
It always returns 0

Comment: @guzmanoj not necessarily...

Comment: @code The return statement in the forEach does essentially nothing, because it is just the callback that is returning. `forEach` always returns `undefined`. From what I can see getAge will always return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the problem was in your getAge method, it was always returning 0.
The return inside the forEach doesn't return the value off of the loop.
Please have a look at the following approach

```
function getAge(name) {
        const person = genesis.balances.find((elm)=> elm.name === name);
        return person ? person.age : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See code comment below

```
function getAge(name) {
  genesis.balances.forEach(element => { // forEach doesn't return anything
    if (element.name == name) {
      // console here shows correct age
      return element.person[0].age;
    }
  });
  return 0;
}
```

You probably want instead something like:

```
function getAge(name) {
  const res = genesis.balances.filter(element => element.name == name);
  if (res.length === 0) return 0; // not found
  return res[0].person[0].age;
}
```

read more about [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

**Comment**: having a person-array under element with "name" is a weird choice, why should a single person-name be mapped to multiple persons?

Comment: I would like to know, how `element => { // this is async` the callback function is async

Comment: Ok, I just gone through the doc, Thanks. But does that mean it's async?

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @NirAlfasi That's not what async means. The next line of code will not execute until the `forEach` is done. That means it is synchronous. It being interruptible or not doesn't come into that definition.

@RajdeepDebnath `forEach` is synchronous and expects a synchronous callback.

Comment: @AaronKvarnlov-Leverty I accept your correction, modified the code-comment accordingly, thanks!